# GitHub: Is it possible to create only one Repository for N repositories?

Tags: github

mine is a somewhat strange question. I begin to explain the current situation so that you can conceptually understand:
I have a Project divided into several Projects:

- APIProjectName;
- ProjectNameJOB;
- ProjectNameWS;
- ProjectNameSPECIAL;
- Etc...

When I uploaded them to github I rightly display these repos like this:

- APIProjectName;
- ProjectNameJOB;
- WSProjectName;
- ProjectNameSPECIAL;
- Etc...

I would like, I don't know if it's possible, that I can see only one repo:

- ProjectName

And that when I click on it I see all the repos in cascade:

- ProjectName

  - APIProjectName
  - ProjectNameJOB
  - WSProjectName

I state I'm not so capable of these things and I don't even know if it's possible to do something like this on GitHub thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

If each if those projects are Git repositories, they always will be displayed in the same list, without hierarchy, on GitHub side.

You might consider creating a `ProjectName` repository in which you add the other repositories as [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules). Then you would have your two-level repositories organization.